# Bind just one argument, later the rest

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, bind

I want to test different algorithms to calculate the speedup (singlecore, cuda, multicore). The function header looks like this:

```
void fraktale_cpu_single(pfc::bitmap * bmp,
                         pfc::RGB_3_t * color_table,
                         const par::complex<float> C)
```

I have always to initialize the same data, so I want to write one function which will call a function pointer.

```
void do_function_with_pic(
    std::function<void(pfc::bitmap * bmp,
                       pfc::RGB_3_t * color_table,
                       const par::complex<float> C)> Func,
    const string pic_name)
```

In single core and cuda no problem, in multicore I want to be able to change the amount of threads which are working on the problem, so my multicore function has one more argument:

```
void fraktale_cpu_multi(size_t threads,
                        pfc::bitmap * bmp,
                        pfc::RGB_3_t * color_table,
                        const par::complex<float> C)
```

I was trying this:

```
do_function_with_pic(bind(fraktale_cpu_multi, 1), "cpu_multi.bmp");
```

but I got an error, because the other arguments are not set, what can i do? - Boost lib is also available!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use **placeholders** for the remaining arguments of your function:

```
#include <functional>

using std::bind;
using namespace std::placeholders; // Namespace for _1, _2, ...

do_function_with_pic(bind(fraktale_cpu_multi, 1, _1, _2, _3), "cpu_multi.bmp");
```

`std::bind` will return a function object that invokes your `fraktale_cpu_multi()` function with the first argument set to `1`, and that forwards its three arguments to `fraktale_cpu_multi()` as the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th argument.

Comment: I'm tempted to "-1" this for the catastrophic suggestion of `using namespace std;`...

Comment: @KerrekSB: Go ahead :-) I'm not suggesting to use that, this is just a sample code. But I'll edit it.

Comment: Yikes, too far in the other direction. `using namespace std::placeholders;` is more reasonable. You can also put the `using` directive into a local scope for the best of both worlds.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Geez, guys, this is just demonstrative code whose purpose is to illustrate how to use `std::bind()`. All the rest is a detail IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
#include <functional>

std::bind(fraktale_cpu_multi, 1,
          std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3)
```